# Tableau creates symbol map rather than filled map

Tags: tableau

I'm a total beginner to tableau so excuse the basic question.

I'm trying to create a filled map using town and state information and color it based on number of customers served in each town. There are no duplicate towns in the data set. I have a hierarchical dimension of town and state and when I put state in as a mark and color it by number of customers, the map turns out exactly as I would like it to. When I then put in town either under the hierarchy of state, or even by itself, the map switches to symbols. Filled map is not an option in the mark type menu, and when I click on filled map in the show me menu it stays as a symbol map.

Is this an issue with my data? Or is it more likely some type error? Both state and town have the proper geographic role. I don't understand why there is a difference between the town and the state data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Tableau can make create a filled map at the city level. It can do counties, states, and countries, but not specific cities. This is where you will get shapes instead of a filled area. It might be possible with a roundabout way but it is not supported natively.